# Trigger to update record action when any of the tables record has either inserted or updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have around 100+ tables in postgreSQL DB. When an insert or update happens in any of the table,I need to capture the record action say insert or update for the record among the.. Is there any way I can handle this in a single trigger since writing trigger for every individual table would be of not proper I believe.could someone help with this

Comment: You can write just one trigger function, if the structure of the tables is the same for the things the trigger function needs to do, but you have to create the trigger using that function for each table. You could use the dictionary to get all tables and create `CREATE TRIGGER` statements from it so that you don't have to write it manually for each table.

Comment: [Here](http://pateldenish.com/2018/07/audit-logging-using-jsonb-in-postgres.html) is a good  example how to implement what @stickybit suggests even if the structure of the tables is _not_ the same.

Answer (score 2):

As @stickybit says you can use the same trigger function but will have to create the trigger for each table; that **is** the proper way not to mention **necessary**. However the table structures do not have to be the same. You can use row_to_json to capture the capture the complete row.

```
create or replace   
function make_copyof_aiudr()
 returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    insert into copyof(table_name, copy_date,action,row_data)
       select TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME
            , now()
            , TG_OP
            , case when TG_OP = 'INSERT'   
                   then row_to_json(new.*)
                   else now_to_json(old.*)
              end ;
     return null; 
end;     
$$;
```

See fiddle for [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7f551d2650e992bcd05145aaceb3b4cd).